# PAGE NOT FOUND- ERROR(404);GET request; django-python

Tags: python, django, get

Lately I have been trying to use the GET request in django-python. However I run into a 404 error when I do so. I want the program to print the parameter given to it.

URL PATTERN :

```
path('add<int:hello>/',views.add,name = 'Add')
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def add(request,num1):
    val1 = request.GET["num1"]
    return HttpResponse(request,"Hello")
```

WHAT I AM SEARCHING ON BROWSER:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/add?1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things are strange or broken here.

---

Given `path('add<int:hello>/', views.add, ...)`,
Django expects that function `views.add` has the following signature:

```
def add(request, hello):
```

---

The pattern `'add<int:hello>/'` expects urls with "add" followed by an integer, such as:

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/add1
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/add2
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/add3
> ...
> ```

and so on.

---

`request.GET["num1"]` expects urls that have `num1=...` in their query string, such as:

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/add1?num1=...
> ```

---

`HttpResponse` expects a string type as its first parameter,
not an `HttpRequest` type as in the posted code.

#### Fixing the problems

This might be close to what you want, and it will work:

```
path('add<int:num1>/', views.add, name='Add')

def add(request, num1):
    return HttpResponse(f"Hello {num1}")

# visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/add1
```

Another variation:

```
path('add', views.add, name='Add')

def add(request):
    num1 = request.GET['num1']
    return HttpResponse(f"Hello {num1}")

# visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/add?num1=123
```

Comment: The second variation worked perfectly! Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/add?hello=1
```

This should work. you need to add the query param name as well.

To get the value you need to use this code:

```
request.GET["hello"]
```

Comment: This time i still get the Page not found error.

Comment: can you hit /add by removing the param? you need to update the path for testing